# How to import precompiled c++ (.so) headers in android jni ndk

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I'm currently working on an Android project and need to integrate precompiled C++ (.so) headers using JNI and NDK. Can someone guide me on how to import these precompiled headers into my Android project effectively?

1. I have library name "TESTLIBRARY" in the maven. which have some java file and cpp with headers file
2. I used above "TESTLIBRARY" in the application gradle dependencies.
3. I want to use "TESTLIBRARY" cpp headers in the "application layer". How I can use it ?

Update :

this might be this best example github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/hello-libs From this example, I also wanted to know, is .h files in include folder is mandatory ?

Comment: When you tried following the [documentation for using pre-built libraries](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#using_prebuilt_libraries), what happened? At this point it is just a plain CMake question, not android. At least edit your question with your CMakeLists.txt and the files you received.

Comment: hey thanks. Tried those and some couple of other resource but nothing helped.

Comment: @Botje having doubt, is it possible to use .h file as import (#include) in app layer from compiled ".so" file. 
Actually I tried extracting .so file and linking in cmake. seems its linked properly but still the import error are persistence. Do you have any idea on this ?

Comment: Edit your question with what you have and what you tried. The header file contains  function *declarations*, and the library contains function *implementations*. This is the way it should be. We will need to see an actual [mre] or at least a CMake file and a list of errors before we can help you.

Comment: @Botje this might be this best example https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/hello-libs
From the above example, I just wanted to know, is .h files in include folder is mandatory ?

Comment: I think you are terribly confused about the whole native aspect of this. In order to use the native code your C++ compiler needs to know what functions and classes are available in the library. The header file (.h) contains this information. So yes, they are mandatory if you want to do anything with the library besides taking up memory.